# Criteria of Countries selection in Natural Earth Data 1:110m?

Tags: geospatial

I'm trying to figure out how Natural Earth Data has selected the countries listed in its [1:110m Admin-0 Countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/) dataset. Indeed there is only 177 countries in this dataset.

Is it Population size ? Territory size ? Something else ?